# What does "re-entrant cavity" mean? How is it different from "normal cavity"?

Tags: microwave

In the field of microwave engineering, what actually does *"Re-Entrant Cavity"* mean? How is it different from normal cavity? What is its structure?

Answer (score 1):

Look in Wikipedia under Reflex Klystron. There you can find a perfect and elaborate explication about a re-entrant cavity. Also in the same chapter you can find a the working of a normal cavity.
The reflex klyston was widely employed in radar systems in the past in an oscillator configuration.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Sir, could u plz provide me the link. I have tried but i didnt get any.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klystron. This should do it.